# error when starting virtual machine (vagrant/ virtualbox)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm following the installation tutorial from [Data Science at the Command Line](http://datascienceatthecommandline.com/) which includes the following steps:

```
$ mkdir MyDataScienceToolbox
$ cd MyDataScienceToolbox
$ vagrant init data-science-toolbox/data-science-at-the-command-line
$ vagrant up
```

When I try the `vagrant up` step, my virtual machine goes into the "Power off" state, giving the following error, in a dialog box illustrated below:

---

The virtual machine **'MyDataScienceToolbox_default_1410032122266_73421'** has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.

Details:

- Error code: `E_FAIL (0x80004005)`
- Component: Machine
- Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}

---

[image]

I'm new to the command line, so if you have the patience, please talk like you talk to a 5 year old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using VirtualBox 4.3.14? Release 4.3.14 has a [known issue](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615) with starting VMs whilst certain security suites are installed on Windows.

You can either try the experimental fix 4.3.15 from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-4.3.15-95713-Win.exe), or roll back to 4.3.12 which you can download from [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/VirtualBox-4.3.12-93733-Win.exe), although bear in mind that older builds may have security vulnerabilities.